# Cloud function(GCP) asking for sign in to receive a request

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I was using for same time Cloud functions from Google Cloud Platform.
But recently on my tests with Postman I've been asked to sign in.
I even allowed to receive requests from unauthenticated sources but the problem persists.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: What's the exact message?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP functions require authentication by default. Earlier this was unauthenticated.

Assign, the `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` to `allUsers`.